# Calculate the sum $\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{2^{n-1}}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, summation

How do I compute the sum:  $$\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{2^{n-1}}{n!}$$

Am I suppose to express this as a power series?  But the problem is I can't find anything on the power series table that this can turn into.  Also, comparison, ratio and limit tests only tell this converges but won't give an exact sum.

Thanks!

Comment: What if you multiply by 2. Would you be able to compute it if it didnt have the $-1$ in the exponent?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Using Taylor series for $\exp(x)$. 
See [Exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function) (for example).

Answer (score 2):

Use  Taylor series$(e^x=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{x^{n}}{n!})$

> $$\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{2^{n-1}}{n!}=\frac12\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{2^{n}}{n!}=\frac{e^2}{2}$$